# Relation between Frobenius norm and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

I'm considering a stochastic multivariate process, the stability of which implies that

- all eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, $i = \overline{1,n}$ of a certain square real-valued matrix $A$ lie within the unit circle.

Besides that we know nothing about $A$. But I also need the condition

- $\| A \|_F < 1$

to hold true and I wonder if there's a connection between these 2 conditions. How much more strict would the latter one be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ and $v$ an associated eigenvector. We may suppose without loss of generalities that $\|v\|_2 =1$. Thus we have $|v_i|\leq 1$ for every $i$ and there exists $j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $|v_j|\geq n^{-1/2}$ since
$$ 1 = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n |v_k|^2\right)^{1/2} \leq \left(n\max_{k=1,\ldots,n}|v_k|^2 \right)^{1/2}$$
Then we have
$$ |\lambda |= |\lambda n^{1/2}||n^{-1/2}|\leq |\lambda n^{1/2}| |v_j| = | n^{1/2}||(Av)_j|=n^{1/2}\left|\sum_{k=1}^nA_{j,k}v_k\right|\leq n^{1/2}\sum_{k=1}^n|A_{j,k}||v_k|\leq n^{1/2}\sum_{k=1}^n|A_{j,k}|\leq n^{1/2}\max_{j=1,\ldots,n}\sum_{k=1}^n|A_{j,k}|.$$

Now, note that by [equivalence between matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Examples_of_norm_equivalence) norms we get
$$n^{1/2}\max_{j=1,\ldots,n}\sum_{k=1}^n|A_{j,k}| = n^{1/2}\|A\|_{\infty} \leq \|A\|_2 \leq \|A\|_F.$$

It follows that your condition $\|A\|_F < 1$ implies that the eigenvalue of $A$ lie in the unit circle. Now, note that the matrix $\frac{2}{3}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ has one eigenvalue equal to $2/3$. However, its Frobenius norm is $\sqrt{3\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2}=\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}>1$.

**EDIT:** In the comment, OP asked about a relation of type $\|A\|_F \leq C\rho(A)$ where $\rho(A)$ is the spectral radius of $A$ and $C >0$ may depend on the dimension $n$, i.e. $A \in \Bbb R^{n\times n}$. Here's a proof that such a bound doesn't exist. Let $n =2 $ and consider the matrix
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & b \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$
Then for $b >1$ we have $\rho(A) = b^{1/2}+1$ and $\|A\|_F = \sqrt{3+b^2}$, suppose such a $C$ exists then we must have
$$ C \geq\frac{\sqrt{3+b^2}}{\sqrt{b}+1}\geq \frac{\sqrt{3+b^2}}{2\sqrt{b}}\geq \frac{\sqrt{b^2}}{2\sqrt{b}}=\frac{\sqrt{b}}{2} \qquad \forall b \geq 1.$$
But note that $\lim_{b\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{b}}{2}=\infty,$ a contradiction.

Comment: Does it also answer your question: "How much more strict would the latter one be?". I'm not sure how quantify "how much" in this context

Comment: The one way to do it I had in mind was: can we also construct the opposite relation of some sort, e.g., $\| A \|_F \le C |\lambda|$? The thing I'm most interested in is how 'big' can the norm get when the eigenvalues are closest to the circle boundaries.

Comment: @Atas On what may $C$ depends? E.g. note that $I_n$ has only $1$ as eigenvalue but its Frobenius norm is $n$ and goes to $\infty$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: The dimension is fixed so that's somewhat out of question. From the norm equivalence relations I get that the rank of $A$ may be involved and since it's unknown we still probably need to assume the dimension as the lower bound.

Comment: @Atas I edited my answer

Comment: The first part can be simplified by noticing that for any matrix norm $\|\cdot\|$ consistent with certain vector norm, we have $\rho(A)\leq\|A\|$. Now the implication follows from the fact that the Frobenius norm is consistent with the vector 2-norm: $\|Ax\|_2\leq\|A\|_F\|x\|_2$ for any vector $x$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Yes it makes sense. This way of upper bounding eigenvalues is very classic though.